# Ajax Comment Upvotes - Votes don't always register

Tags: theme-development, ajax, javascript, comments

I'm trying to create a simple **ajax**-based comment upvoting system for Wordpress. I've managed to build most of it, but now it seems that most of the time the upvotes don't register. They do register sometimes (but only maximum of 2, even though I did not implement a limit), and the Ajax call gets a successful response (so the PHP function is executed I guess).

Any ideas where I'm going wrong (this is my first Ajax project)?

**PHP function:**

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_comment_meta_update_vote', 'comment_meta_update_vote' );

function comment_meta_update_vote( ) {
    check_ajax_referer( 'upvote_nonce' );

    $comment_id = $_POST['comment_id'];
    $vote_score = get_comment_meta($comment_id , 'vote', true);
    ++$vote_score;
    update_comment_meta($comment_id , 'vote', $vote_score, true );


      $response['type'] = 'success';
      $response = json_encode( $response );
      echo $response;
    die(); 
}
```

**Javascript Function:**

```js
function updateVote( comment_id ){

    jQuery(function($) {
      $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
      dataType : 'json',
      url : upvote_ajax.ajax_url,
      data : {
        action: 'comment_meta_update_vote',
        comment_id: comment_id,
        _ajax_nonce: upvote_ajax.nonce
      },
      success: function( response ) {
         if( 'success' == response.type ) {
            // console.log('success');
         }
         else {
           // alert( 'Something went wrong, try logging in!' );
         }
      }
    }) })};
```

Comment: Is there any error in the browser console?

Comment: No errors in the browser console...

Comment: Update: Found the error: `update_comment_meta($comment_id , 'vote', $vote_score, true );` should not have a TRUE parameter. Removing that made it work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this and inform me what you got in the console. and sure `console.log` the  `type`

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_comment_meta_update_vote', 'comment_meta_update_vote' );

function comment_meta_update_vote( ) {
check_ajax_referer( 'upvote_nonce' );

$comment_id = $_POST['comment_id'];
$vote_score = get_comment_meta($comment_id , 'vote', true);
$vote_score++;
$updated = update_comment_meta($comment_id , 'vote', $vote_score );

  if($updated){
    $msg = 'success';
  }else{
    $msg = 'failed';
  }
  $response = array('type' => $msg);
  wp_json_encode( $response );

die(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I found the error just before you posted:  Found `update_comment_meta($comment_id , 'vote', $vote_score, true );` should not have a TRUE parameter. Removing that made it work again.